# Updating ID of wp_posts and post_id of wp_postmeta causes losing content in the web page, why?

Tags: wordpress

I need to change the ID values of some specific posts in wordpress. I am doing it like below:

```
update wp_posts set ID = ID + 10000 where ID > 3110;
update wp_postmeta set meta_id = meta_id + 10000, 
                           post_id = post_id + 10000 where post_id > 3110;
```

The query works fine and does his job; however I don't see the content on my webpage after executing the updates above. Why? Am I missing updating any other table? Shouldn't I go on seeing the same content?

Any help or advice would be appreciated.